# total number of posts using facebook graph api

Tags: javascript, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-javascript-sdk, facebook-like

I want to get total number of posts done by admin , here is a ptv sports page id , i tried my page id even , it is returning Data:array[object] = length 25, i have displayed it but if posts are 400 then what should i do do manage uninformed posts and show all of them

```
        function p_post() {
        FB.api("/209652442394600?fields=posts{admin_creator}", function (response) 
             {   
              var t = response.posts.data.length;  });
                                   }
```

the answer by default is 25, manage it

Comment: 25 is the default `limit` value; you can specify a higher one, but you can not go arbitrarily high – there’s a _limit_ to the `limit` as well. After that, you have to follow the pagination links the API provides to get more results.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
     function p_post() {
                FB.api("/209652442394600/posts?fields=admin_creator,name&limit=250", function (response) {
                    var t = response.data.length;
                    document.getElementById('tposts').innerHTML = t;
            });
            }
```

it works